# Dual booting Ubuntu with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7

I already have Ubuntu and I want to dual boot windows alongside this beautiful operating system. Can I get a tutorial from someone where I don't have to re-install Ubuntu and start from scatch? Thank you, Ubuntu users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the help section of Ubuntu where you have steps to install Windows after you've installed Ubuntu or you already have it installed.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Also, there's a similar question which might help you

[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)